# xml formatting change after removing unwanted attributes.

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader, xmldocument, xml-formatting

I am using a technique like this to read in a directory of Xml files to an XmlDocument Object.

```
private static void StripAttributes(string filePath)
    {
        Contract.Requires(filePath != null);
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        var encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath, encode))
        {
            xmlDocument.Load(sr);
        }
```

That works, but when rendering the outputted Xml in a text editor, single quotes around the attributes are now double, and the Child Nodes are on a different line.

Example from before:

```
<xml>
  <xml2>
     <xmlField id='foo' string='bar'><xmlValue>foobar</xmlValue></xmlField>
  </xml2>
</xml>
```

Example after formatting:

```
<xml>
  <xml2>
     <xmlField id="foo">
        <xmlValue>foobar</xmlValue>
     </xmlField>
  </xml2>
</xml>
```

I need the original format to stay the same for comparison purposes.

Any ideas to how I could preserve the original format of the Xml?

Answer (score 0):

**Whitespace**

Your first issue is whitespace. In XML, this is usually unimportant so by default, `XmlDocument` will normalise any significant whitespace, which is what you're seeing here.

To change this behaviour, set `PreserveWhitespace = true` before loading your XML:

```
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument
{
    PreserveWhitespace = true
};
```

**Quotes**

Your second issue relates to the quote characters.  Single or double is valid, but the default in .NET is double.  Both DOMs will re-write your XML using an `XmlWriter` internally, which uses this default.  You can, of course, specify your own `XmlWriter` instance.

The guidance is to use `XmlWriter.Create` factory methods and specify any features using `XmlWriterSettings`, however this won't work in this case.  You will have to explicitly create an instance of `XmlTextWriter` and change the `QuoteChar`:

```
var writer = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, encoding)
{
    QuoteChar = '\''
};

using (writer)
{
    xmlDocument.WriteTo(writer);
}
```

**LINQ to XML**

As an aside, I'd strongly suggest looking at LINQ to XML instead of the old `XmlDocument` API.  To get the similar behaviour in `XDocument`, you would parse and write like so:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
doc.WriteTo(writer);
```

If, as your code suggests, you are removing attributes then code as simple as this would remove all attributes with the name `string` from elements with the name `xmlField`:

```
doc.Descendants("xmlField")
    .SelectMany(e => e.Attributes("string"))
    .Remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.  Will the XmlWriter work with the StreamReader, or do I need to replace the StreamReader?

Comment: The `StreamReader` is used for *reading*, the `XmlWriter` is used for *writing*.  You haven't shown how you're writing the resulting XML, but this is what you'll need to use to do it if you want to keep the quotes as single.

Comment: Will "xmlDocument.Save(filePath);" work or will I need to modify how I Save/Write the Xml?

Comment: No, you need to use `xmlDocument.WriteTo(writer)` - this is in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you cannot! With Microsoft.Net implementation of xml rendering, the renderer always reformats the output. Either XmlDocument or XDocument with any kind of setting. In one our my projects (Efatura in Turkey) the xml files are xades signed and should not be changed. We have realized that just only rendering and saving without any changes alters something in xml file and renders signature invalid. Also if for example the input xml is only one line (without any whitespace) The parsers (all) fail to parse the document. The effect we observed is the parser misses some elements acting as if they are not there.

For your situation I suggest try to use other xml implementations. For our case, since we dont need to change sth, we first keep all of the string seperately then parse a copy of document to extract information from it. When finished throw it to garbage.

For single line xml we used XmlReader but altered matching mechanism.